# Equivalent function to .push() in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to have a dynamic array with objects inside.  I need a function that is equivalent to the .push() function in Javascript but in Java. The errors occur in the `pipe.push(new Pipe())` inside of the setup function.

```
Bird bird;
Pipe[] pipe;
boolean keyDown = false;

  void setup() {
    size(800, 800);
    frameRate(60);
    bird = new Bird();
    pipe.push(new Pipe()); 
  }

  //------------------------------------------------------------

  void draw() {
    background(0);


    bird.gravity();
    bird.show();
    bird.edge();

  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------

  void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 32) {
      if(keyDown == false) {
        bird.jump();
        keyDown = true;
      }
    }
  }

  void keyReleased() {
    keyDown = false;
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Would you mind share the current java code you have?

Comment: For Arrays or Lists? For arrays, you can't; they have a static size. For Lists, use `add`.

Comment: Now that you posted your code, you can't `push` to an array in java. You may be better served by a `List`. Also, your array is not even initialized, so even if arrays had such a method, this wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: 'The errors'. *What* errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in Java arrays are fixed size. you have to specify the size and then cant expand them. Unfortunate to change the size you need to declare new array.

But fortunately Java provides different data structures e.g. list, set which can grow dynamically as size of increases.

eg

```
    ArrayList<Pipe> pipes = new ArrayList();

    pipes.add(new Pipe()); 
    pipes.add(new Pipe()); 


for(Pipe pipe : pipes){
   pipe.update();
}
```

Comment: If you are going with Arraylist you can use something like this -

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
pipe.push(new Pipe());
```

simply isnt possible in Java. In Java, an array has a **fixed** size. You can't dynamically add/remove slots.

If you need that, you can use [List/AbstractList](https://www.callicoder.com/java-arraylist/) for example.

Beyond that, the real answer here is: don't start by assuming that Java has anything to do with JavaScript. So, when you think "let's use arrays in Java", then start by researching how Java treats arrays. Don't assume that anything there is like in JavaScript.